# How to avoid PHP automatically casts an int to a float

Tags: php, types, casting

I have a method like this:

```php
    protected function iAcceptOnlyFloats(float $iAcceptOnlyFloats): void
    {
        Assertion::float($iAcceptOnlyFloats);
        $this->iAcceptOnlyFloats = $iAcceptOnlyFloats;
    }
```

The problem is that if I pass an integer to the method, it is automatically transformed to a float:

```php
$this->iAcceptOnlyFloats(1); // passes 1.0
```

I've declared strict types at the beginning of the file, but this seems not having fixed the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: I'm running PHP 7.4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't enforce it.

Per [the manual on strict typing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict),

> In strict
> mode, only a variable of exact type of the type declaration will be
> accepted, or a TypeError will be thrown. **The only exception to this
> rule is that an integer may be given to a function expecting a float.**